# Speed up parsing in Elasticsearch Logstash Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am new to ELK [ Elasticsearch Logstash and Kibana].  I installed Elasticsearch Logstash and Kibana in one server. Then installed Logstash in two machines. Total RAM in each system is around 30 GB. Total file to parse is around 300 GB. It took 6 days to filter out the searchd item[I searched for 10 digit number, timestamp and Name of one API from all these logs]and dispay it in Kibana. Am i doing something wrong here. Is there any other way to speed up this process.

Thanks in Advance,
Paul

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out based on the time in Kibana UI. Also, if you are pushing to Logstash from any beat logger, Logstash takes time to push it to Elastic Search.

There are many beat applications which will directly push the data to Elastic Search.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am able to filter out based on time in Kibana. I need to push only the filtered values to elasticsearch. I will try using beat logger.

Comment: Currenly I am not using any beat application. I searched and found file beat can be used to push data to logstash . Do I need to install Elasticsearch logstash and kibana in all the three machines?? As of now, I have installed logstash in all three machines and directing the output to same elasticsearch.  Does the master slave setup speeds up the log parsing.

Comment: Setup and configure ELK in one of the high performance machine. From slave machines, just use the file beat or any file poller to push it to Logstash or even directly to ElasticSearch. If you want filter out, you can do that in filebeat itself before pushing it to elastic. Read its documentation, you will get it. Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: In Slave machines , do I need to install separte instance of elasticsearch and logstash.

Comment: No need. Just use any file poller to read from the file and push it to the ES or Logstash{If you use Logstash, you need to push it to ES from Logstash}